# How can I add label and reference to each row of a table?

Tags: tables, hyperref, labels

I have 2 tables, and they have a common column so I want each row from the first table to point to the corresponding row of the second and the other way around. And also, if it is possible that the label be the value inside the cell.

Here is part of the first table:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Test files}
\label{my-label}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
File name & Number of depots & Number of vehicles & Number of customers \\ \hline
0.txt        \label{0txt1}   \ref{0txt2}      & 2                & 4                   & 18                  \\ \hline
1.txt        \label{1txt1}   \ref{1txt2}      & 4                & 16                 & 50                  \\ \hline
2.txt        \label{2txt1}   \ref{2txt2}      & 4                & 8                   & 50                  
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

Here is part of the second table:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\cline{2-13}
                                     & \multicolumn{12}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{COST}}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              \\ \cline{2-13} 
                                     & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{NO OPTION}}                                                                     & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{REINITIALIZATION}}                                                              & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{PERMUTATION}}                                                                   & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{PERTURBANCE}}                                                                   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textit{File name}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{None}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{2Opt}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{All}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{None}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{2Opt}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{All}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{None}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{2Opt}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{All}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{None}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{2Opt}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{All}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{0.txt        \label{0txt2}   \ref{0txt1}}              &                                    &                                    &                                   &                                    &                                    &                                   &                                    &                                    &                                   &                                    &                                    &                                   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{1.txt        \label{1txt2}   \ref{1txt1}}              &                                    &                                    &                                   &                                    &                                    &                                   &                                    &                                    &                                   &                                    &                                    &                                   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

This is how the labels and references look for the first and second table:

`\label{0txt1}   \ref{0txt2}`

`\label{0txt2}   \ref{0txt1}`.

At the moment I can only go from the second table to the first not the other way around.

Comment: What do you mean by "point to"? Do you want a hyperlink in the table that you can click and it will jump from row X in table 1 to row X in table 2? If so, what should this clickable link say? Should it be the `0.txt` that is clickable, which from table 1 will jump to `0.txt` in table 2?

Comment: Please make a complete example document with two tables, and say what should link to what (do you really want to inflict `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%` on yout tables?

Comment: I have added a part of the second table. @Werner yes, that is exactly what I would want.

Comment: Interestingly, you need to add a caption.  Also, all of the references simply link to the caption: \ref{table.1} and \ref{table.2}.  You really don't need any other labels.

Comment: That's rely the last solution I want to use, I have 32 rows in the tables and I would like to make each table full page.

Comment: Sorry, that's how hyperref works.

Comment: Now if you want to use \hypertarget and \hyperlink, then you can get more specitic.

Comment: I only knew about label and ref and I thought \hyperlink was only to point you to a webpage. What do I need to change in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with linking to the line below the one you want seems to be inherent in tabulars.  At first I compensated by putting an invisible target in the line above.  Later I achieved the same effect using \raisebox (see [hyperref and tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186098/problem-with-hyperref-and-tabular-not-table?noredirect=1#comment430473_186098)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftoolbar=true,pdfpagemode=UseNone,pdfstartview=FitH,colorlinks=true}

\newlength{\offset}
\newcommand{\raisetarget}[1]% #1 = label
{\raisebox{\offset}[0pt][0pt]{\hypertarget{#1}{}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\setlength{\offset}{\baselineskip}% must be outside tabular
\centering
\caption{Test files}
\smallskip
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
File name & Number of depots & Number of vehicles & Number of customers \\ \hline
\raisetarget{0txt1}\hyperlink{0txt2}{0.txt}
  & 2 & 4 & 18 \\ \hline
\raisetarget{1txt1}\hyperlink{1txt2}{1.txt}
  & 4 & 16 & 50 \\ \hline
\raisetarget{2txt1}\hyperlink{2txt2}{2.txt}
  & 4 & 8 & 50 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{second table}
\smallskip
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\setlength{\offset}{\baselineskip}% must be outside tabular
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\cline{2-13}
 & \multicolumn{12}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{COST}}} \\
\cline{2-13} 
 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{NO OPTION}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{REINITIALIZATION}} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{PERMUTATION}}
 & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{PERTURBANCE}} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textit{File name}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{None}} &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{2Opt}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{All}}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{None}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{2Opt}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{All}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{None}}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{2Opt}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{All}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{None}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{2Opt}}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{All}} \\
\hline
 \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\raisetarget{0txt2}\hyperlink{0txt1}{0.txt}}
 & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
 \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\raisetarget{1txt2}\hyperlink{1txt1}{1.txt}}
 & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
 \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\raisetarget{2txt2}\hyperlink{2txt1}{2.txt}}
 & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: hypcap and \hypcapspace did nothing for me.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you are trying to do then you want to have entries in two tables which function as links to corresponding entries in the other table. To do this you will have to create a dummy counter so that `\label` and `\ref` can track the different table entries. You probably also want to create the links directly using `hyperref` rather than with `\ref`.

Some variation on the following should do the the trick:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{MyLabels}
\newcommand\MyLabel[2]{\refstepcounter{MyLabels}\label{#1-#2}%
\ifx#11\hyperref[#1-2]{#1}\else\hyperref[#1-1]{#1}\fi%
}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Test files}
\label{my-label}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
File name & Number of depots & Number of vehicles & Number of customers \\ \hline
\MyLabel{0txt}{1}       & 2                & 4                   & 18                  \\ \hline
\MyLabel{1txt}{1}       & 4                & 16                 & 50                  \\ \hline
\MyLabel{2txt}{1}       & 4                & 8                   & 50
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\cline{2-13}
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{NO OPTION}}
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{REINITIALIZATION}}
& \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{PERMUTATION}}
& \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{PERTURBANCE}}
\\ \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textit{File name}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{None}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{2Opt}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{All}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{None}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{2Opt}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{All}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{None}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{2Opt}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{All}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{None}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{2Opt}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{All}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\MyLabel{0txt}{2} }              &
&                                    &
&                                    &
&                                   &
&                                    &
&                                    &
&                                   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\MyLabel{1txt}{2}  }              &
&                                    &
&                                    &
&                                   &
&                                    &
&                                    &
&                                   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

The `\newcounter{MyLabels}` defines a counter that is then used to track the labels in your two tables via the `\refstepcounter{MyLabels}` in `\MyLabel` macro. The command `\MyLabel` is used to insert the hyperlink between the entries in the two tables. The syntax is:

```
\MyLabel{text}{table number=1 or 2}
```

This add a link around `text` to the corresponding entry in the other table. If your text is going to be reasonably complicated, or if it differs between the two tables, then you will probably need to add a third `label` argument to the macro. Similarly, if you need these links between more than two tables you'd probably need to specify the `source` and target tables in the macro.

Comment: Your example seems to take me right after the link not on it. For example if I want to go to 0.txt I am able to see from 1.txt down.

Comment: could you tell me why that happens?

Comment: @AlexandruCimpanu I agree that this happens but, unfortunately, I have no idea what the cause i or how to fix it. I suspect that hyperref is not always able to accurately locate where a link points to, but it might be a bug in my implementation or a problem/limitation with pdf....

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is in line with what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\linkbacktext}[3]{% \linkbacktext{<to>}{<name>}{<text>}
  \hyperlink{#1}{\smash{\raisebox{\normalbaselineskip}{\hypertarget{#2}{\raisebox{-\normalbaselineskip}{#3}}}}}}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \caption{First table}\label{tbl:label-1}
  \begin{tabular}{llll}
    \toprule
    File name & Number of depots & Number of vehicles & Number of customers \\
    \midrule
    \linkbacktext{0txt2}{0txt1}{\texttt{0.txt}} &  2 &  4 & 18 \\
    \linkbacktext{1txt2}{1txt1}{\texttt{1.txt}} &  4 & 16 & 50 \\
    \linkbacktext{2txt2}{2txt1}{\texttt{2.txt}} &  4 &  8 & 50 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \caption{Second table}\label{tbl:label-2}
  \begin{tabular}{llll}
    \toprule
    File name & Number of depots & Number of vehicles & Number of customers \\
    \midrule
    \linkbacktext{0txt1}{0txt2}{\texttt{0.txt}} &  2 &  4 & 18 \\
    \linkbacktext{1txt1}{1txt2}{\texttt{1.txt}} &  4 & 16 & 50 \\
    \linkbacktext{2txt1}{2txt2}{\texttt{2.txt}} &  4 &  8 & 50 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

`\linkbacktext{<to>}{<name>}{<text>}` inserts a link called `<name>` with text `<text>`. It also provides a hyperlink to `<to>`.

Comment: When using this method the red rectangle continues even after my table stops. Is it because `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` ?

Comment: @AlexandruCimpanu: Different to what is shown in my example? I don't understand.

Comment: If I don't use \toprule and \buttomrule like your example I get a red rectangle until the end of the page. I am using MiKTeX as compiler.

Comment: @AlexandruCimpanu: I'm unable to reproduce that under TeX Live (and I don't have MiKTeX installed); I removed `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` and the output remains the same.

Comment: I recompiled and the problem did not appeared again. But it still looks like it's taking me to the page rather then the row.

Comment: @AlexandruCimpanu: With such misguided hyperlinks you should get warnings in your `.log`. I'm guessing you're using a different technique, perhaps solely relying on `\label`-`\ref`. I don't receive those when I compile the above MWE. You must be doing something else.