# Problem with hyperref and tabular (not table)

Tags: tables, hyperref

The link to the target inside a tabular is too low.  This is not inside a float, so hypcap and \hypcapspace have no effect.  Is this a known problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftoolbar=true,pdfpagemode=UseNone,pdfstartview={FitH},colorlinks=true}

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{test1}{normal anchor}

\hyperlink{test1}{link}

\begin{tabular}{c}
\hypertarget{test2}{tabular}
\end{tabular}

\hyperlink{test2}{link}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not really related to the tabular you see the same on the first link if you do `\mbox{}\hypertarget{test1}{normal anchor}` the anchor is at the reference point, so on the baseline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The target is put on the base line.

- `\raisebox` can be used to raise the target.
- pdfTeX provides `\vadjust pre{...}` to put something before the current line.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
  pdftoolbar=true,
  pdfpagemode=UseNone,
  pdfstartview={FitH \hypercalcbp{\paperheight}},
  colorlinks=true
}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
  \raisebox{\heightof{T}+1pt}[0pt][0pt]{\hypertarget{test1}{}}%
  tabular1
\end{tabular}

\hyperlink{test1}{link}

\begin{tabular}{c}
  \vadjust pre{\hypertarget{test2}{}}%
  tabular2
\end{tabular}

\hyperlink{test2}{link}
\end{document}
```

### `pdfstartview`

The argument `top` is *not* known by the PDF reader. AR9/Linux even refuses to display the file, because of the invalid syntax.

- Either the vertical number can be given, which is interpreted with the unit `bp`, the default unit in PostScript and PDF.
- Or the value can be calculated via `\hypercalcbp`:

  ```
  pdfstartview=FitH \hypercalcbp{\paperheight}
  ```

  or

  ```
  pdfstartview=FitH \hypercalcbp{\paperheight-\topmargin-1in}
  ```

  to get on top of the header line or

  ```
  pdfstartview=FitH \hypercalcbp{\paperheight-\topmargin-1in-\headheight-\headsep}
  ```

  to get on top of the text body.

Comment: Or you can just put an invisible target one line higher in the tabular.  As for top, I just copied from the manual and it seemed to work.

Comment: Also, \baselineskip=0pt inside a tabular for some reason.  Actually, that could explain it.

Comment: On further reading, the "top" in the manual is a number (like you said).  However, if you leave off the number it should default to the top of the page (which is what I want).  The Firefox previewer does not, but then it can't handle multifile hypertext at all.