# Hyperlinks and page breaks in a cross-referenced TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, page-breaking

The TOC entries requirements are :

1. The TOC page breaks defined by (2) and (3) should be automatic (no need to manually add `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}` as described at [Split the Table of Contents in two pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6489/split-the-table-of-contents-in-two-pages/6494?s=1%7C0.2360#6494) )
2. Breaks should be forbidden between a level and a sublevel.
3. As long as (2) is satisfied, a level should have the minimal number of breaks, with the highest priority going to the deeper level, that is :

   - (3.1) as long as (2) is satisfied, a level has N breaks if it cannot stand on less than (N+1) pages without an Overfull \vbox.
   - (3.2) the (Max Depth) level breaking has no meaning anyway.
   - (3.3) for X ranging from (Max Depth-1) to (Min Depth), the unavoidable breaks of an X-depth level are :
   - - (3.3.1) at lines which don't conflict with (2).
   - - (3.3.2) at lines which don't add any break to any deeper level.
   - - (3.3.3) at the lowest lines preventing an Overfull \vbox.
   - (3.4) there is no break between "Contents" and the following item since it would conflict with (2).
4. The cross-ref between the level titles and the TOC should be accurate.

The problem is :

- Conditions (3.1) and (3.3.2) don't work since it should break the TOC pages before (section 1.32) and before (part 2).
- Condition (4) doesn't work from chapter titles to the TOC entries since you always will be directed to the first sub-level TOC entry.
- Condition (4) doesn't work from other level titles to the TOC entries if they start a new page in the TOC (see subsection 1.32.2) without manually adding `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}`.

The `\titleformat{\chapter}` command is placed after `\begin{document}` in order to "Contents" not to act as a dead link.

Indeed that link would be quite undead here since (4) doesn't work for chapter titles.

Placing `\titleformat{\chapter}` in the preamble won't solve the problem anyway.

I already tried the `\Hy@raisedlink` soultion described at [Vertical position after navigating to hyperref hypertargets from hyperlinks seems too low](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77919/vertical-position-after-navigating-to-hyperref-hypertargets-from-hyperlinks-seem?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The result was an error maybe due to hyphenation as described at [`\Hy@raisedlink` block hyphenation and perturbate line breaking](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281978/hyraisedlink-block-hyphenation-and-perturbate-line-breaking?noredirect=1&lq=1)

For chapters, the problem seems to be due to the way the `.toc` file is written since the `\hypertarget {\the part.\thechapter}{}` should be written before the corresponding `\contentsline` (`.toc` code given below).

Thanks in advance for your help.

PS : Not sure this working example is really minimal since I also loaded extra packages that may interfer with titles, that is :

- `chngcntr` as described at [Incorrect hyperlinks when \part is used. How can I correct this?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262743/incorrect-hyperlinks-when-part-is-used-how-can-i-correct-this?s=1%7C0.3804)
- `fancyhdr` as described at [fancyhdr: How get part on even and chapter on odd pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49222/fancyhdr-how-get-part-on-even-and-chapter-on-odd-pages?rq=1)

Here is the .tex file :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\raggedbottom
\setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}
\usepackage{etoc}
\etocsetstyle{part}{\nopagebreak\etocskipfirstprefix}{\nopagebreak{\penalty 9999}}{\makebox[2em][r]{\etocnumber}\hspace{2\wordsep}\etocname\dotfill\etocpage\par}{\nopagebreak{\penalty -9999}}
\etocsetstyle{chapter}{\nopagebreak\etocskipfirstprefix}{\nopagebreak{\penalty 9999}}{\makebox[4em][r]{\etocnumber}\hspace{2\wordsep}\etocname\dotfill\etocpage\par}{\nopagebreak{\penalty -9999}}
\etocsetstyle{section}{\nopagebreak\etocskipfirstprefix}{\nopagebreak{\penalty 9999}}{\makebox[6em][r]{\etocnumber}\hspace{2\wordsep}\etocname\dotfill\etocpage\par}{\nopagebreak{\penalty -9999}}
\etocsetstyle{subsection}{\nopagebreak\etocskipfirstprefix}{\nopagebreak{\penalty 9999}}{\makebox[8em][r]{\etocnumber}\hspace{2\wordsep}\etocname\dotfill\etocpage\par}{\nopagebreak{\penalty -9999}}
\etoctocstyle{1}{Contents}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhf[LO,RE]{Author}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{\headrulewidth}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[clearempty,explicit]{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\partmark}[1]{\markboth{\thepart. #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\titleformat{\part}{\Huge\bfseries}{\thepart}{2\wordsep}{\hyperlink{\thepart}{#1}\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{\thepart}{}}}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{2\wordsep}{\hyperlink{\theHsection}{#1}\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{\theHsection}{}}}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{2\wordsep}{\hyperlink{\theHsubsection}{#1}\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{\theHsubsection}{}}}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{\baselineskip}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage[hidelinks,linktoc=all]{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\theHchapter}{\thepart.\thechapter}
\renewcommand{\theHsection}{\thepart.\thesection}
\renewcommand{\theHsubsection}{\thepart.\thesubsection}
\begin{document}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{Contents\markright{#1}{}}{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\MakeUppercase\rightmark}
\tableofcontents
\titleformat{\chapter}{\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{2\wordsep}{\hyperlink{\theHchapter}{#1}\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{\theHchapter}{}}}

\cleardoublepage
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\MakeUppercase\leftmark}
\part{The First Part}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepart.\thechapter. \MakeUppercase\rightmark}

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

Some text.

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

Some text.

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}
\section{A section}

\subsection{A subsection}

\subsection{A subsection}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

Some text.

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}
\cleardoublepage
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\MakeUppercase\leftmark}
\part{The Second Part}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepart.\thechapter. \MakeUppercase\rightmark}

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{A section}

\end{document}
```

and here is the .toc file :

```
\@ifundefined {etoctocstyle}{\let \etoc@startlocaltoc \@gobble \let \etoc@settocdepth \@gobble \let \etoc@depthtag \@gobble }{}
\hypertarget {I}{}
\contentsline {part}{I\hspace {1em}The First Part}{5}{part.1}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}A chapter}{7}{chapter.I.1}
\hypertarget {I.1}{}
\hypertarget {I.1.1}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}A section}{7}{section.I.1.1}
\hypertarget {I.1.2}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2}A section}{7}{section.I.1.2}
\hypertarget {I.1.3}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.3}A section}{7}{section.I.1.3}
\hypertarget {I.1.4}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.4}A section}{7}{section.I.1.4}
\hypertarget {I.1.5}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.5}A section}{7}{section.I.1.5}
\hypertarget {I.1.6}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.6}A section}{7}{section.I.1.6}
\hypertarget {I.1.7}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.7}A section}{7}{section.I.1.7}
\hypertarget {I.1.8}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.8}A section}{7}{section.I.1.8}
\hypertarget {I.1.9}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.9}A section}{7}{section.I.1.9}
\hypertarget {I.1.10}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.10}A section}{7}{section.I.1.10}
\hypertarget {I.1.11}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.11}A section}{7}{section.I.1.11}
\hypertarget {I.1.12}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.12}A section}{7}{section.I.1.12}
\hypertarget {I.1.13}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.13}A section}{7}{section.I.1.13}
\hypertarget {I.1.14}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.14}A section}{7}{section.I.1.14}
\hypertarget {I.1.15}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.15}A section}{8}{section.I.1.15}
\hypertarget {I.1.16}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.16}A section}{8}{section.I.1.16}
\hypertarget {I.1.17}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.17}A section}{8}{section.I.1.17}
\hypertarget {I.1.18}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.18}A section}{8}{section.I.1.18}
\hypertarget {I.1.19}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.19}A section}{8}{section.I.1.19}
\hypertarget {I.1.20}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.20}A section}{8}{section.I.1.20}
\hypertarget {I.1.21}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.21}A section}{8}{section.I.1.21}
\hypertarget {I.1.22}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.22}A section}{8}{section.I.1.22}
\hypertarget {I.1.23}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.23}A section}{8}{section.I.1.23}
\hypertarget {I.1.24}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.24}A section}{8}{section.I.1.24}
\hypertarget {I.1.25}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.25}A section}{8}{section.I.1.25}
\hypertarget {I.1.26}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.26}A section}{8}{section.I.1.26}
\hypertarget {I.1.27}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.27}A section}{8}{section.I.1.27}
\hypertarget {I.1.28}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.28}A section}{8}{section.I.1.28}
\hypertarget {I.1.29}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.29}A section}{8}{section.I.1.29}
\hypertarget {I.1.30}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.30}A section}{9}{section.I.1.30}
\hypertarget {I.1.31}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.31}A section}{9}{section.I.1.31}
\hypertarget {I.1.32}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.32}A section}{9}{section.I.1.32}
\hypertarget {I.1.32.1}{}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.32.1}A subsection}{9}{subsection.I.1.32.1}
\hypertarget {I.1.32.2}{}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.32.2}A subsection}{9}{subsection.I.1.32.2}
\hypertarget {I.1.33}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.33}A section}{9}{section.I.1.33}
\hypertarget {I.1.34}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.34}A section}{9}{section.I.1.34}
\hypertarget {I.1.35}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.35}A section}{9}{section.I.1.35}
\hypertarget {I.1.36}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.36}A section}{9}{section.I.1.36}
\hypertarget {I.1.37}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.37}A section}{9}{section.I.1.37}
\hypertarget {I.1.38}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.38}A section}{9}{section.I.1.38}
\hypertarget {I.1.39}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.39}A section}{9}{section.I.1.39}
\hypertarget {I.1.40}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.40}A section}{9}{section.I.1.40}
\hypertarget {I.1.41}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.41}A section}{9}{section.I.1.41}
\hypertarget {I.1.42}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.42}A section}{9}{section.I.1.42}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}A chapter}{11}{chapter.I.2}
\hypertarget {I.2}{}
\hypertarget {I.2.1}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.1}A section}{11}{section.I.2.1}
\hypertarget {I.2.2}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.2}A section}{11}{section.I.2.2}
\hypertarget {I.2.3}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.3}A section}{11}{section.I.2.3}
\hypertarget {I.2.4}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.4}A section}{11}{section.I.2.4}
\hypertarget {I.2.5}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.5}A section}{11}{section.I.2.5}
\hypertarget {I.2.6}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.6}A section}{11}{section.I.2.6}
\hypertarget {I.2.7}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.7}A section}{11}{section.I.2.7}
\hypertarget {I.2.8}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.8}A section}{11}{section.I.2.8}
\hypertarget {I.2.9}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.9}A section}{11}{section.I.2.9}
\hypertarget {I.2.10}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.10}A section}{11}{section.I.2.10}
\hypertarget {I.2.11}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.11}A section}{11}{section.I.2.11}
\hypertarget {I.2.12}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.12}A section}{11}{section.I.2.12}
\hypertarget {I.2.13}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.13}A section}{11}{section.I.2.13}
\hypertarget {I.2.14}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.14}A section}{11}{section.I.2.14}
\hypertarget {I.2.15}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.15}A section}{12}{section.I.2.15}
\hypertarget {I.2.16}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.16}A section}{12}{section.I.2.16}
\hypertarget {I.2.17}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.17}A section}{12}{section.I.2.17}
\hypertarget {I.2.18}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.18}A section}{12}{section.I.2.18}
\hypertarget {I.2.19}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.19}A section}{12}{section.I.2.19}
\hypertarget {I.2.20}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.20}A section}{12}{section.I.2.20}
\hypertarget {I.2.21}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.21}A section}{12}{section.I.2.21}
\hypertarget {I.2.22}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.22}A section}{12}{section.I.2.22}
\hypertarget {I.2.23}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.23}A section}{12}{section.I.2.23}
\hypertarget {II}{}
\contentsline {part}{II\hspace {1em}The Second Part}{13}{part.2}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}A chapter}{15}{chapter.II.1}
\hypertarget {II.1}{}
\hypertarget {II.1.1}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}A section}{15}{section.II.1.1}
\hypertarget {II.1.2}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2}A section}{15}{section.II.1.2}
\hypertarget {II.1.3}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.3}A section}{15}{section.II.1.3}
\hypertarget {II.1.4}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.4}A section}{15}{section.II.1.4}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}A chapter}{17}{chapter.II.2}
\hypertarget {II.2}{}
\hypertarget {II.2.1}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.1}A section}{17}{section.II.2.1}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key was to modify `\contentsline` to add the `\hypertarget` on the same line.  Having `\hypertarget` aim one line too low is a known problem in certain environments (like tabular), which can be fixed using `\raisebox` or `\vadjust pre{...}`.  See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186098/problem-with-hyperref-and-tabular-not-table).

Note: hyperref modifies `\addtocontents` and `\contentsline` to include the hypertarget name.  I simply added `.cross` to this name for the cross reference.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\raggedbottom
\setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}
\usepackage{etoc}
\etocsetstyle{part}{\nopagebreak\etocskipfirstprefix}{\nopagebreak{\penalty 9999}}{\makebox[2em][r]{\etocnumber}\hspace{2\wordsep}\etocname\dotfill\etocpage\par}{\nopagebreak{\penalty -9999}}
\etocsetstyle{chapter}{\nopagebreak\etocskipfirstprefix}{\nopagebreak{\penalty 9999}}{\makebox[4em][r]{\etocnumber}\hspace{2\wordsep}\etocname\dotfill\etocpage\par}{\nopagebreak{\penalty -9999}}
\etocsetstyle{section}{\nopagebreak\etocskipfirstprefix}{\nopagebreak{\penalty 9999}}{\makebox[6em][r]{\etocnumber}\hspace{2\wordsep}\etocname\dotfill\etocpage\par}{\nopagebreak{\penalty -9999}}
\etocsetstyle{subsection}{\nopagebreak\etocskipfirstprefix}{\nopagebreak{\penalty 9999}}{\makebox[8em][r]{\etocnumber}\hspace{2\wordsep}\etocname\dotfill\etocpage\par}{\nopagebreak{\penalty -9999}}
\etoctocstyle{1}{Contents}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhf[LO,RE]{Author}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{\headrulewidth}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[clearempty,explicit]{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\partmark}[1]{\markboth{\thepart. #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\titleformat{\part}{\Huge\bfseries}{\thepart}{2\wordsep}{\hyperlink{part.\theHpart.cross}{#1}}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{2\wordsep}{\hyperlink{section.\theHsection.cross}{#1}}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{2\wordsep}{\hyperlink{subsection.\theHsubsection.cross}{#1}}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{\baselineskip}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage[hidelinks,linktoc=all]{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\theHchapter}{\thepart.\thechapter}
\renewcommand{\theHsection}{\thepart.\thesection}
\renewcommand{\theHsubsection}{\thepart.\thesubsection}

\let\oldcontentsline=\contentsline
\def\contentsline#1#2#3#4{\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{\raisebox{\baselineskip}{\hypertarget{#4.cross}{\relax}}#3}{#4}}

\begin{document}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\MakeUppercase\rightmark}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{Contents\markright{#1}}
\tableofcontents
\titleformat{\chapter}{\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{2\wordsep}{\hyperlink{chapter.\theHchapter.cross}{#1}}

\cleardoublepage
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\MakeUppercase\leftmark}
\part{The First Part}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepart.\thechapter. \MakeUppercase\rightmark}

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

Some text.

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

Some text.

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}
\section{A section}

\subsection{A subsection}

\subsection{A subsection}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

Some text.

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}
\cleardoublepage
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\MakeUppercase\leftmark}
\part{The Second Part}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepart.\thechapter. \MakeUppercase\rightmark}

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\section{A section}

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{A section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It solves the second and the third problems, thus voted up. However I red at [link]https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145314/renewcommand-for-commands-defined-with-def?s=1%7C1.1998 and in other posts that the use of `\renewcommand` was preferable to the use Tex commands such as `\let` and `\def`. Is there a way to do that ? I am trying to do it but for now I am getting a "memory excess", probably a bad loop.

Comment: I was looking at the definition of \contentsline inside hyperref at the time, but \renewcommand is fine.  OTOH, \let is different.  You could achieve the same effect using etoolkit, but frankly that package scares me silly.

Comment: Isn't it `etoolbox` instead of `etookit` ?

Comment: Anyway you're right about the fact that `\def\contentsline#1#2#3#4` can be replaced by `\renewcommand{\contentsline}[4]` in order to obtain the same result. Note that in both cases the link from the TOC to the last chapter isn't very accurate. That problem can be solved by adding either `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` before `\end{document}`. I'm still looking for a solution to the first problem : automatic page breaks in the TOC.

Comment: Tricky!  You would need to know how many subsections are coming up later and maybe use \needspace.

Comment: When I applied the above solution to an example which titles contained characters with various heights and depths such as `f` and `p`, I got a (quite ugly) TOC with various line spacing. The solution is to replace `\raisebox{\baselineskip}` by `\raisebox{\baselineskip}[0.75\baselineskip][0.25\baselineskip]`. One could also expand the line spacing in order the links not to cover one another.

Comment: Using a \strut is easier and basically equivalent.  (e.g. `{\strut #1}`)

Comment: You're right. `\strut\raisebox{\baselineskip}` do the trick at once.

Comment: I'm trying to set the headers by using `pagestyles` of `titlesec` instead of `fancyhdr`. There might be a counter problem with my code since it gives (I Nothing) (II The First Part) (III The Second Part) ...
Code :
`\let\originalpart\part
\renewcommand{\part}[1]{
\cleardoublepage
\renewpagestyle{plain}{\sethead[][][]{}{}{\thepart\ \parttitle}}
\originalpart{#1}\renewcommand{\parttitle}{#1}
\renewpagestyle{plain}{\sethead[\thepart.\thechapter\ \chaptertitle][][]{}{}{\thepart.\thechapter\ \chaptertitle}}
\pagestyle{plain}}`

Comment: You lost me.  You might try this as a new question with a new MWE.

Comment: OK. To be continued at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375439/interference-between-titlesec-and-parttitle-in-a-book-with-automatic-page-breaki